# Displaying a separate 404 not found page inside of a module in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-routing

In my Angular application, I would like to have two separate Page Not Found pages.

In the app root, there is one in case the user goes something like: http://localhost:4200/xyz. This is fine.

However, I added one to my admin module which has an AuthGuard on it. If the user is logged in and navigates to http://localhost:4200/admin/xyz I would like them to go to my not found page within the admin module. For some reason they are getting logged out and redirected back to the Login page.

Please refer to the sample project below (attempt to go to /admin, login, then change the path to /admin/xyz and hit enter):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7tjyqx

Also, same thing happens with crisis-center which is not a protected module. Try going to /crisis-center/xyz and you will get redirected back to crisis-center instead of crisis - page not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because services in angular (AuthService) are not shared as singletons for lazy-loaded modules. so every time you go to http://localhost:4200/admin/xyz directly from the address bar, a new service instance is created which sets isLogged to false and you are thrown to the Login page. However, if you log in and visit through 
routerLink to  http://localhost:4200/admin/xyz, you will get the no page

found and that is because you are inside same service instance of the module.

Comment: Excellent answer. So I can either stop lazy loading the modules so the entire app reloads each time or not be able to do it. Is it common to have a not found page within each separate module (feature of the system)? It seems like most people have one on the outer level, but the problem with that is my features have different looks and feels. So if a user is in the Admin feature I want the page not found to be inside that template, if the user is in another feature I want the page not found to be inside of that template. So is it basically not possible unless I stop lazy loading?